# R: How do I substitute some old strings in a dataframe with new strings?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe of the list of student:

```
No   name      class
1    Isaac     Physics
2    Napoleon  History
3    Sigmund   Psychology
4    Ludwig    Music
5    LeBron    Sport
6    Jeff      Economy
```

I want to change the name of some students, the new name is in the second dataframe:

```
No   Old        New
1    Isaac      Newton
2    Sigmund    Freud
3    LeBron     James
```

So the student data will look like this:

```
No   name      class
1    Newton    Physics
2    Napoleon  History
3    Freud     Psychology
4    Ludwig    Music
5    James     Sport
6    Jeff      Economy
```

I can use `substitute`, but it takes too much time. I want to do it quickly by making use of the second dataframe which contains new name database. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df$name <- recode(df$name, !!!deframe(new[c("Old","New")]))
```

**Output**

```
  No     name      class
1  1   Newton    Physics
2  2 Napoleon    History
3  3    Freud Psychology
4  4   Ludwig      Music
5  5    James      Sport
6  6     Jeff    Economy
```

---

**How it works**

1. `deframe` will turn a two column dataframe into a named vector.
2. `!!!` is special syntax for `recode` to apply a named vector to `df$name`.

Note: `tidyverse` is a collection of very useful packages for data science/manipulation. This loads several packages. `deframe` is from the library `tibble` and `recode` is from `dplyr`.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(No = 1:6, name = c("Newton", "Napoleon", "Freud", 
"Ludwig", "James", "Jeff"), class = c("Physics", "History", "Psychology", 
"Music", "Sport", "Economy")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

new <- structure(list(No = 1:3, Old = c("Isaac", "Sigmund", "LeBron"
), New = c("Newton", "Freud", "James")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: So helpful! Thanks a lot for your kindness! I'll try to learn about `recode` and `deframe` :D

Answer (score 1):

We can use a join `on` the 'name' and the 'Old' column from the first and second dataset and assign the 'New' from the second to the 'name' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, name := New, on = .(name = Old)]
```

-output

```
 df1
   No     name      class
1:  1   Newton    Physics
2:  2 Napoleon    History
3:  3    Freud Psychology
4:  4   Ludwig      Music
5:  5    James      Sport
6:  6     Jeff    Economy
```

NOTE: Using `data.table`, we can do this much efficiently

---

Or use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1$name <- coalesce(setNames(df2$New, df2$Old)[df1$name], df1$name)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(No = 1:6, name = c("Isaac", "Napoleon", "Sigmund", 
"Ludwig", "LeBron", "Jeff"), class = c("Physics", "History", 
"Psychology", "Music", "Sport", "Economy")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(No = 1:3, Old = c("Isaac", "Sigmund", "LeBron"
), New = c("Newton", "Freud", "James")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```